# What is Goku's red aura form in the new Dragon Ball Super opening?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

What is Goku's red aura form in the new Dragon Ball Super opening? Is it regular Kaioken? Is it Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan with Kaioken? Is it his Super Saiyan God form? Is it something new? You can see the opening here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FN57gmQlmLU

(The question of the topic is what form it is, the other questions are explanatory.)

[image: Goku red aura form]

Update: 03/08/2017 . Super Saiyan Blue transformation was seen first in merchandising toys. Some people is saying the image behind this chocolate Goku merchandising could be Goku's new form and related to this red aura form we see in the opening.

[image]

And recently a tweet was made by a Dragon Ball Super writer saying he's expecting a new form

[image]

Answer (score 5):

We won't actually know until we see the episode that Goku performs it but... he seems to be in his base form but with red aura instead of his original white aura!! But how is this form above Super Saiyan Blue? I am kinda curious and excited. And BTW I came here for an answer but I didn't find one lol. But it doesn't seem to be Kaioken or Super Saiyan God.

Comment: His hair is standing up like it does when he is a Super Sayian

Comment: I think it's kaioken but in some special form, may be it's super kaioken (the one he made against Paikuhan) or kaioken with god ki or kaioken in super saiyan god (red) form

Comment: I've seen a new theory which says it's a new form of ki which is seen first being used by Toppo and Jiren.

Comment: @Pablo Just an idea, but if the 6 Saiyans (Goku, Vegeta, Gohan, Caulifla, Kale, and Cabba) made a new SSJ God out of one of the group, Caulifla has the closest "normal" hairstyle to look like that image in SSJ God.

Answer (score 3):

From a spoiler from a japanese magazine about the fight between Goku and Jiren

> Aparently it's kaioken times 20, which is told Goku uses against Jiren without effect on his adversary. But there is no mention if it's Kaioken in base form, on top of Super Saiyan Blue or what.

Answer (score 1):

I guess,it's the 10x kaioken form at normal goku level but ki at God's level that once whis talk to Oracle fish

Link Below:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk4uLWBeS-E

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the red aura Super Saiyan God which Beerus saw in his vision in the start of Dragon Ball Super Saga.

Comment: which episode? I dont remember it