# Where does this picture of Goku possible new form/transformation comes from?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

A new picture of a Goku possible new form/transformation has appeared and some people is speculating that it could have to do with this another picture of a possible new Goku form/transformation [What is Goku's red aura form in the new Dragon Ball Super opening?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/what-is-gokus-red-aura-form-in-the-new-dragon-ball-super-opening) .

Where does this new picture come from?

[image]

Note: can't find the picture with the tools suggested.

Comment: Not necessarily , he's asking what magazine or what rumour is this from ?

Comment: I tried to look it before asking and I couldnt find its source.

Comment: I found it on [DeviantArt by NekoAR](http://nekoar.deviantart.com/art/Son-Goku-US-Artwork-New-Transformation-689845770) using the said tool. Apparently, the artist traced the original poster?

Comment: It could it be, it's possible. Have you found the other one with the kanjis and the logos as being released by a Dragon Ball Super producer?

Comment: it seems user apaws is right, that blog also claims it was released by that guy who is a dragon ball producer http://diostuber.blogspot.com.ar/2017/06/dragon-ball-super-nueva-transformacion.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: original visual]

Producer Hiroyuki Sakurada released a statement about *Dragon Ball Super*'s new key visual for the "Universal Survival" saga: [From Toei Animation]

> The curtain finally rises on the Tournament of Power, where the strongest warriors in the history of *Dragon Ball Super* are gathering! The new key visual for the Tournament of Power is finally finished! It depicts Goku as he tries to break new ground in order to face off against the mightiest of foes in the midst of the fierce battle that is the Tournament of Power! What sort of formidable foes are in store?! How will Goku battle them? And what new ground will he break?! Don't miss *Dragon Ball Super* as the hype ramps up for the unprecedented battle that will unfold at the Tournament of Power!!

Comment: so that guy released it? Was it a poster or something?

Comment: released that text with this visual

Comment: Accorded to this video, the producer added this note. Is it true? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MavUe5YLMS4 "It presumes the appearence/form/shape of Goku who tries to wake up into a new state/ground in order to fight the strongest enemy in the intense fight during the tournament of power!"

Comment: The full image was also released recently . I'll update it after I find the image