# Does the super saiyan god return to Dragon Ball Super ? (possible spoilers)

Tags: dragon-ball-series, japanese-language, dragon-ball-super

> So there are rumours that the super saiyan god (red) is going to return to the Dragon Ball Super anime series. There is a text from a japanese magazine which supposedly says so, and even though I can't assert it's true, I indeed can read "super saiyan god" written in japanese in the text.

Can anyone confirm it or deny it by reading what the japanese magazine says in this text? (or through other source?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been confirmed by a Dragon Ball Super writer, Super Saiyan God will return to Dragon Ball Super.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. It's in the episode where hit fights the pride troopers, episode 104 or 103.

Answer (score 1):

Super Saiyan God (the red haired form) appeared during episode 110. It was when Goku was testing the forms against Jiren in order to know his power and effectiveness as opposed to Jiren.

Answer (score 0):

We currently have 6 Saiyans still in the ring: Goku, Vegeta, Gohan, Caulifla, Kale, and Cabba.

If they were forced to work together, you could see them use their power to turn one of the group into a SSJ God.

Looking at the red form aura highlighted in this question (in the 2nd picture):
[What is Goku's red aura form in the new Dragon Ball Super opening?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38814/what-is-gokus-red-aura-form-in-the-new-dragon-ball-super-opening)

Caulifla is the only current Saiyan with the correct hairstyle to potentially look like that while a SSJ God.